# Having trouble using sigaction with a timer signal

Tags: c

Hi everyone
i'm trying to use sigaction() however without success
this is my code:

```
int main()
{

struct sigaction act, oact;
act.sa_handler = (void *)g;

sigaction(SIGVTALRM,&act,&oact);

struct itimerval tv;
tv.it_value.tv_sec = 2; //time of first timer
tv.it_value.tv_usec = 0; //time of first timer
tv.it_interval.tv_sec = 2; //time of all timers but the first one
tv.it_interval.tv_usec = 0; //time of all timers but the first one

setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &tv, NULL);

for (;;);
}
```

this is g():

```
void g( void ){

    printf("I'M NOT IN G!!");
    for (;;);
}
```

when i run the code i get stuck in the first for(;;) loop without ever getting to g().
why don't i get to g() if i defined it as the function that handles the signal?

thank you

Comment: Are your calls to `sigaction` and `setitimer` returning 0 (meaning no error)? It looks like the usage of those functions is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should ensure that the input `struct sigaction` structure is clean:

```
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
act.sa_flags = 0;
act.sa_handler = g;
```

Then, you should suspend the process rather than use a for-loop "spin wait":

```
sigset_t mask;
sigprocmask(0, NULL, &mask);
sigdelset(&mask, SIGVTALRM);
sigsuspend(&mask);
```

Lastly, your signal-handler should be defined correctly and not use the printf() function, which is considered unsafe in the presence of signals and shouldn't be used in a signal-handler. Instead, it should set an atomic flag:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t g_called;

void g(int sig) {
    g_called = 1;
}
```

Comment: Calling `printf` (or other non-async-signal-safe functions) from a signal handler is valid and safe as long as a non-async-signal-safe function is not interrupted by the signal handler. For instance, if the only code running when the signal occurs is `for (;;);` then you can use any functions you want from the signal handler.

Comment: `sigsuspend()` would normally make sense but in this case it will wait forever, as the `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` timer only runs while the process is executing in user mode.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you're using an uninitialized `sigaction` structure. Either initialize it with:

```
struct sigaction act = {0};
```

Or use `memset` to clear it before calling `sigaction`.

Comment: There's 2 other problems as well, stdout is likely line buffered, so the printf won't show - and secondly, you shouldn't call printf in a signal handler as printf isn't async signal safe.(though it's probably harmless for a small testcase like this)

Comment: As I commented on Steve's answer, calling `printf` is perfectly safe in a signal handler as long as no other function which is not async-signal-safe could be executing when the signal handler is invoked. This is specified carefully by POSIX at the end of section 2.4.3 of XSH.

Comment: All-zero is not a portable initialization of a `sigset_t`; `sigemptyset()` or `sigfillset()` must be used.

Comment: Fair enough, you still need to initialize the `sigset_t`. But at least the flags, etc. won't be random.